# Symfony pagination inside in entity

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, doctrine

I have entities (let's say `Posts`).
Inside each post I want to make possible pagination ("Next" and "Previous" buttons).

I can link to previous post and to the next. The problem is: I can make disabled button "Previous" if there's no posts to the left (if you're in first post, then it should be impossible to get to the `0` post), and what about getting post count? 
`{{ entity | length }}` is displaying current post `id`.

What I want to achieve is that: when user is on latest post (let's say there are 300 posts), and on the 300-th post there should be disabled "Next" button (because there's no posts below this post)

P.S. I'm using symfony 2.7 and Twig as a templating engine

Comment: I think showing us some code could help us understand .... your controller, and your full Twig template for instance

Comment: Welcome to the jungle of non-readers of the StackOverflow's lineguides like: [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for asking question like this one. Will read these guidelines before asking my next question. Thank you, Mr. @gp_sflover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont quite get the question but based on

> What I want to achieve is that: when user is on latest post (let's say
>   there are 300 posts), and on the 300-th post there should be disabled
>   "Next" button (because there's no posts below this post)

If all you want is a paginator, why dont you use this [bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) (KNP) ?

Bundles are the essence of Symfony2

Comment: This is what I did. My question isn't actual atm.